# Proper terminology for force/work to move something a certain distance in zero gravity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces

I was asked a question along the lines of "how much force is needed to move 1kg 1 meter in zero gravity?" (no time limit, so quickly or slowly, and no deceleration to stop it at 1 meter). I replied "1 kg meter". I'm now questioning my use of "force" in describing this, and think my intuitive understanding is perhaps off.

Is the "1 kg m" even correct, and is it "work energy", "force", or some other quantity? It seems that if I nudge such a thing in zero gravity, and it continues moving indefinitely, "work" done increases over time, but that can't be right.

Comment: The units of force are $kgm/s^2$. What happens when you apply one Newton to a mass of 1kg?

Comment: The proper answer to the question you were asked is  "INSUFFICIENT DATA FOR MEANINGFUL ANSWER."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1\:\mathrm{kg\cdot m}$ does not mean anything, no.

- **Force** has units of Newton $\:\mathrm{[N]=[kg\cdot m/s^2]}$
- **Work** has units of Joules $\:\mathrm{[J]=[N\cdot m]=[kg\cdot m^2/s^2]}$

> (no time limit, so quickly or slowly, and no deceleration to stop it at 1 meter)

- When you say this, you are removing all restraints. If I push an object in outerspace (not experiencing any external forces at all) infinitely little (with infinitely little force) then it experiences an infinitely small acceleration. Thus it gains an infinitely small speed. But it *stays*! That is, this speed obtained *will not be stopped*. So if you have infinitely much time, then the object **will** pass the chosen distance - after quite a while.

The point is that if there is no time limitation, then **any non-zero force** can move the object 1 meter ahead. It is not hard to make something move, it is only hard to make it move *fast* (and if other forces are pushing back it might of course also be hard to overcome them - but this not the case in your setup.)

> It seems that if I nudge such a thing in zero gravity, and it continues moving indefinitely, "work" done increases over time, but that can't be right.

Remember that work is only done *while* the force is applied.

$$W=\int \vec F \cdot d\vec x$$

If you give the object "a nudge" then work is only done while this nudge is being giving - that is, while you are in contact with it and pushing. During the rest of it's motion, which is not stopped by anything, no work is done at all.